# Blur only one contour in image using python opencv cv2

Tags: python, opencv, blur, contour

This blurs only the contour but is slow. Is there a faster way?

```
#img is the image
#cnt is a contour
#blur is a blurred copy of the image

temp = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(temp,[cnt],0,255,-1)
pp = np.transpose(np.nonzero(temp))   #all pixelpoints in contour

for k in range(0, len(pp)):
  img[ pp[k,0],pp[k,1] ] = blur[ pp[k,0],pp[k,1] ]
```

Adding details: The general type of operation I want to speed up is: for some input image, blur (or filter in other ways) a copy of the image, find contours in the blurred copy, copy all and only pixels within contours onto the original image.

I have read that for loops are relatively slow in Python. [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) looks like the tool for this. Help me with the syntax. This does not work:

> img = np.where([temp != 0], blur, img)

edit: this works and is twice as fast as the first code block.

```
#img is the image
#cnt is a contour
#blur is a blurred copy of the image
temp = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(temp,[cnt],0,255,-1)
x = np.where(temp == 0)
img[x] = blur[x]
```

Any way to speed up the operation more?